# Flex: getting the previous value of a combobox when it changes

Tags: apache-flex, events, combobox

I need to know the value from which a combo box is changing, when it changes. I've been all through the documentation for the events, and none of them let you know what the value is before user interaction changes it. (`currentStateChanging` is a total red herring!) Handling the `open` event and saving the value isn't a solution, because there are other ways to change the value.

I'm using the Flex 3.5 SDK.

Comment: You usually have the old value stored in a model somewhere before it is overwritten with the new value. That's about all I can say without knowing what it is that you're trying to do. (btw, I don't see how currentStateChanging could be a red herring: it is dispatched when a view starts _changing its current state_ ...)

Comment: currentStateChanging refers to the state of the component, not the value of selectedItem

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var currentVal : Object;

private function onChange(newVal) : void {
    // currentVal stores your previous value - do something with it
    currentVal = newVal;
}

<mx:ComboBox change="onChange(event.target.selectedItem)"/>
```

I just used the "changing" event on a Spark ComboBox to solve this very problem but it's not available on the mx version

Also - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499676/flex-combobox-prechange-event?rq=1)

Comment: That's not w/out gotchas either. It won't catch assignments to value or selectedIndex.  
The link you provided gives solutions with varying degrees of acceptability, however, the description of the valueCommit event promises to catch all cases, so I'm going to see if I can make backups w/that. Obviously, I'm also going to have to provide my own event, since the event will need to embed the old value. Otherwise, the combo's owner's handler won't be able to get the old value, because it'll be clobbered by the valueCommit handler.

Comment: It all depends what you're trying to achieve.  If you need to perform some action when the value is changed by either user interaction or programmatically, then valueCommit is a good bet.  Watch out for infinite loops.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is having the old value as well as the new value of a combo box when the user changes the value. Since there are multiple ways to do this, it's not enough to handle the close event. I came up w/a solution, but it doesn't get any points for neatness and its reliability is less than perfect. But it's probably can't be improved upon in 3.5.

Comment: Why isn't the "change" event enough if you only want to catch it when the user changes it?

Comment: Because "change" doesn't let you know what the previous value was. Not in 3.5

Answer (score 0):

I've come up w/a solution, but it's not perfectly reliable (since it makes assumptions about how it will work in other SDKs) and its elegance is wanting:

```
<mx:ComboBox    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" valueCommit="OnChangeAnyway()" change="OnChange()">
<mx:Metadata>
    [Event(name='traceable_change', type="assets.LineComboChangeEvent")]
</mx:Metadata>

<mx:Script><![CDATA[
    public static const CHANGE:String = 'traceable_change';

    private var m_oOld:Object;
    private var m_oNew:Object;
    private var m_bCallLaterPending:Boolean = false;  //This is necessary, because I found OnChangeAnyway() could be called any number of times before OnChange() is

    private function OnChange():void {
        var oNewEvent:LineComboChangeEvent = new LineComboChangeEvent(CHANGE, m_oOld);   //there's nothing special in this class
        dispatchEvent(oNewEvent);
    }

    private function OnChangeAnyway():void {
        if (!m_bCallLaterPending) {
            m_bCallLaterPending = true;
            callLater(function ():void { m_bCallLaterPending = false;}, []);   //presumably, whatever is passed to callLater() will be executed after everything else currently queued
            m_oOld = m_oNew;
            m_oNew = value;
        }
    }
]]></mx:Script>
```

`m_oNew` is obviously redundant because that value will be available to whatever handles `traceable_change`, but it does explain why I have to barrel-shift these objects.
There are a couple of reasons why I don't consider this reliable:

1. It assumes that the `valueCommit` handler will be called ahead of the `change` one. On my system, it always seems to, but I don't see that promise anywhere.
2. It assumes that whatever `callLater()` calls will be called after `change` is. See concerns for 1.

Answer (score 0):

I've come to the conclusion that there isn't an answer :( The best workaround is to override all possible ways there are to set the value of a combo box, plus handle any events that involve the user changing the value, back up that value and then you have a trail of previous values. Then, put a lot of comments saying

> this is a 3.5-necessary kluge! If doing this on another SDK you might have to change it!

=======